# Specifying other color for link to my site pages and other for external links

Tags: django, tinymce

Dose somebody know that is solution for my problem?

Comment: By way of digression django-tinymce with tinymce javascript package is secured? It is free of javescript and other attacks of this type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Style external links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379752/css-style-external-links)

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy to accomplish with some JavaScript. If you aren't comfortable with JavaScript, you can always look for existing solutions in the form of a plugin for jQuery, or whichever your JS library of choice is.

jQuery example:

```
  $("a[href^=http]").each(
    function(){
      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
        $(this).addClas('colored');
      }
    }
  )
```

Comment: JavaScript and jQuery is some kind of black magic for me for present day. But it seems that I need to learn how to whrowing spells in those languages. But it does not change the fact that You help me and I the nearly future I will use Your script in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with [pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379752/css-style-external-links).

Some further possibilities are explained in this [post](http://www.csstemplatesweb.com/css-articles/how-to-style-external-links-with-css/).