# Exclude image tag from external link styling

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've added styling with an icon for all external links [with help of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379820).

Here's the styling:

```
a[href]:not(:where(
  /* exclude hash only links */
  [href^="#"],
  /* exclude relative but not double slash only links */
  [href^="/"]:not([href^="//"]),
  /* domains to exclude */
  [href*="//mydomain.de"],
  )):after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    content: '\f0c1';
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

Problem: There is an icon on external links on images, too.

Now I want to exlude these external links on images.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and what specifically isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David Thank you for your notice. I've added some more information to my question.